# Can uproot4 write TTrees?

Tags: uproot

uproot3 had some limited writing capabilities, is writing TTrees possible in uproot4? In particular, I would like to create a skim, just discarding branches and one or two simple event-level cuts.

Comment: Not yet. That was the one missing feature that was delaying the uproot4 → uproot name transition, but there are too many other things waiting to go ahead, so this feature will have to wait until after the transition on Dec 1. Since this is StackOverflow, I should come back to this question and weave a proper answer when the feature does exist.